# how do I connect my Python reverse shell with a pc that is not in my local network

Tags: python, python-3.x

I coded a reverse shell (like a backdoor) that I want to use over my rasperry pi but that rasperry pi isnt connected to the same wifi as my pc. So can anyone tell how this works? If you need code ask in the answers and I will send some. Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by getting a dynamic dns and learn about port forwarding on your router.

Comment: Your PC end needs to be open to the Internet, by setting up a port-forwarding entry in your router/modem so that anyone outside can connect to it. Then your reverse shell needs to connect to your external IP address (see https://ifconfig.me/) rather than your LAN IP address to establish connection. Note connecting to your external IP address from within your LAN wont work, the Raspberry needs to be outside your LAN for this test to work.

Comment: Also, presumably your external IP is dynamic (changes every time your modem reconnects) so you might want to use a Dynamic DNS service to keep a DNS address always up to date with your current IP so that it can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a networking problem, your computer is in a different net than you raspberry so you have to route you packets over the differents networks. I'll let you an abstract drawing of what i think your problem is.
[image: abstract situation]
The clouds represent networks and those circles with an R inside represent routers.
Your task should be forward your packets from your computer in the router R, and R' for you to be able to connect to your raspberry. It is not necessary a dynamic [Domain Name System](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/)(DNS) because the only task of a dns is translate the name of a web url to an IP address and if you have the IP address of R' your job is done.
I hope you find this answer good and i'll leave you the task of find a way to forward packets